# How to make Stata margins work for user-written model

Tags: stata, margins

I wonder, what requirements must a user-written estimation and/or prediction program satisfy in order for standard Stata `margins` command to be able to work with it?

I have created a toy "estimation" program with a prediction module, but when I run `margins, dydx(x)` after `myreg y x`, Stata throws `r(103)` ("too many specified") and produces nothing. Can anyone modify my code so that `margins` could work with it?

Yes, I know that if `e(predict)` is not returned, `margins` assume linear prediction and work OK, but eventually I need to write a nonlinear model and estimate marginal effects for it.

```
program mypred
    version 13
    syntax name [if] [in] 
    marksample touse
    local newVar = "`1'"
    mat b = e(b)
    local columnNames: colfullnames b
    tokenize `columnNames'
    gen `newVar' = b[1,1] + b[1,2] * `2'
end

program myreg, eclass
    version 13
    syntax varlist(min=2 max=2) [if] [in] 
    marksample touse
    tempname b V
    matrix input b = (1.1, 2.3)
    matrix input V = (9, 1 \ 1, 4)
    matrix colnames b = _cons `2'
    matrix colnames V = _cons `2'
    matrix rownames V = _cons `2'
    ereturn post b V, esample(`touse')
    ereturn local predict "mypred"
    ereturn local cmd "myreg"
    ereturn display
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer. If there is such a one-stop location within the Stata documentation that answers your question, I'm not aware of it.

The recommendation is to read, at least, the whole entry: [[R] margins](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rmargins.pdf). Here is a list of conditions that should be considered:

> `margins` cannot be used after estimation commands that do not produce
>   full variance matrices, such as exlogistic and expoisson (see [R]
>   exlogistic and [R] expoisson).
>
> `margins` is all about covariates and
>   cannot be used after estimation commands that do not post the
>   covariates, which eliminates gmm (see [R] gmm).
>
> `margins` cannot be used
>   after estimation commands that have an odd data organization, and that
>   excludes asclogit, asmprobit, asroprobit, and nlogit (see [R]
>   asclogit, [R] asmprobit, [R] asroprobit, and [R] nlogit).

From another subsection:

> ... as of Stata 11, you are supposed to set in e(marginsok) the list
>   of options allowed with predict that are okay to use with margins.

Consider also inspecting (`help viewsource`) user-written commands from experienced user/programmers who allow for this in their commands. [Maarten Buis](http://maartenbuis.nl/software/index.html) is one of them. (You can run `search maarten buis, all` to search within Stata.)